# Using tidyverse, how can I replace NAs with character pattern, but remove entire row if no match is found?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

Hello I have a sample dataset as follows.

```
# Load the tidyverse package
library(tidyverse)

# Create the dataset
id <- 1:6
model <- c("0RB3211", NA, "0RB4191",
           NA, "0RB4033", NA)
UPC <- c("805289119081", "DK_0RB3447CP_RBCP  50", "8053672006360",
         "Green_Classic_G-15_Polar_1.67_PREM_SV", "805289044604",
         "DK_0RB2132CP_RBCP  55")
df <- tibble(id, model, UPC)
```

[image]

For the missing values in 'model' column, if its corresponding UPC starts with DK, I need to extract 7-digit number and letter after first underscore and then put it into the column 'model'. For example, for the second row, I need to put "0RB3447" into the 'model' column, for the fourth row, I need to delete the whole row and for the last row, I need to put "0RB2132" into the 'model' column.

Here is my expected result:
[image]

```
# Manipulate the dataset
df_cleaned <- df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(model = ifelse(is.na(model) & str_detect(UPC, "^DK"),
                        str_extract(UPC, "\\d{2}RB\\d{4}"),
                        model)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(!(is.na(model) & str_detect(UPC, "[^0-9]")))

# Display the cleaned dataset
print(df_cleaned)
```

However, it only returns this wrong result.
[image]

How can I modify my previous code?
Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `ifelse`, another option is `coalesce` with the existing `model` so that it only replaces the NAs in the model with the substring from the UPC extracted with `str_replace`.  Later keep only the rows where the model starts with 0.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
 df %>% 
  mutate(model = coalesce(model,
      str_replace(UPC, ".*_(0[^_]+\\d+)[A-Z]+_.*", "\\1"))) %>% 
   filter(str_detect(model, "^0"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
     id model   UPC                  
  <int> <chr>   <chr>                
1     1 0RB3211 805289119081         
2     2 0RB3447 DK_0RB3447CP_RBCP  50
3     3 0RB4191 8053672006360        
4     5 0RB4033 805289044604         
5     6 0RB2132 DK_0RB2132CP_RBCP  55
```

---

In the OP's code, `rowwise` is not needed as `ifelse` is vectorized.  Also, `\\d{2}` will not match some of the strings as `0RB..`, shows only a single digit and not 2 before RB.  Therefore, use `+` to denote one or more digits

```
df %>%
  mutate(model = ifelse(is.na(model) & str_detect(UPC, "^DK"),
                        str_extract(UPC, "(?<=_)\\d+RB\\d{4}"),
                        model)) %>%
  filter(complete.cases(model))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
     id model   UPC                  
  <int> <chr>   <chr>                
1     1 0RB3211 805289119081         
2     2 0RB3447 DK_0RB3447CP_RBCP  50
3     3 0RB4191 8053672006360        
4     5 0RB4033 805289044604         
5     6 0RB2132 DK_0RB2132CP_RBCP  55
```

Answer (score 0):

I also couldn't get `str_match` to work, but I did come up with a workaround:

```r
df_cleaned <- df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(model = case_when(is.na(model) & grepl("DK", UPC) ~ str_split(UPC, "_")[[1]][2], 
                           TRUE ~ model)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(!(is.na(model) & str_detect(UPC, "[^0-9]")))
```

`grepl` detects if "DK" is in UPC. `str_split` creates a list of 1 item with the three strings that are separated by the underscores (_). You want the second item, hence `str_split(UPC, "_")[[1]][2]`.

Also, I find `case_when()` to be a cleaner alternative to `ifelse()`. It works like

```r
case_when([if statement] ~ [then statement],
          TRUE ~ [then statement])
```

where the TRUE essentially means "if none of the above are true".

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 5 × 3
     id model     UPC                  
  <int> <chr>     <chr>                
1     1 0RB3211   805289119081         
2     2 0RB3447CP DK_0RB3447CP_RBCP  50
3     3 0RB4191   8053672006360        
4     5 0RB4033   805289044604         
5     6 0RB2132CP DK_0RB2132CP_RBCP  55
```